# Arbitrary query params on Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js, `query-params` can be used with `link-to` to generate links that include a query string. For instance:

```
<p>{{link-to "Search" 'search' (query-params q='london')}}</p>
```

What is not immediately apparent is how to pass **arbitrary** parameters to `query-params`. This is: passing an object whose key/values will make the query string. For example the following (which throws an error):

```
// At the component
myParams: {
  q: 'london',
},

{{!-- At the template --}}
<p>{{link-to "Search" 'search' (query-params myParams)}}</p>

<!-- The end result -->
<p><a href="/search?q=london">Search</a></p>
```

Looking at Ember's source code, I can see how this can be done. I can put together an object that looks like those returned by `query-params`. True enough, the following object will be interpreted by `link-to` the way I want:

```
// At the component
myParams: {
  isQueryParams: true,
  values: {
    q: 'london',
  },
},

{{!-- At the template --}}
<p>{{link-to "Search" 'search' myParams}}</p>
```

However, that looks like an internal, private interface to me. So my question is: is there an approved way to do this? (And what is it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution at the moment is to create your own helper:

```
// app/helpers/hash-query-params.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function hashQueryParams([hashParams]) {
  return Ember.Object.create({
    isQueryParams: true,
    values: hashParams
  });
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(hashQueryParams);
```

then use it like

```
<p>{{link-to "Search" 'search' (hash-query-params myParams)}}</p>
```

This could be supported by Ember. Open an RFC or create an addon with this helper! :)